# Does SASS support element specification as nested selector?

Tags: css, sass

Let's say you have this SASS definition (unreal example):

```
.class {
    margin: 1px;
    background: black;
    color: white;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}

a.class {
    margin: 1px;
    background: black;
    color: yellow;

    &:hover {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Now, can we put the `a` specification of the same class as a nested selector? E.g. something like this (pseudo-code):

```
.class {
    margin: 1px;
    background: black;
    color: white;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }

    // Some selector to show that the current class
    // should be applied to this element (?)
    a.& {
        color: yellow;

        &:hover {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's a possibility. Plus, in this specific case you are not inheriting any thing from the original class at all, which makes the nesting sort of useless. If you were to inherit more from the initial class, I think the better way would still be to use an `@extend .class` for the `a`.

Comment: not possible.  you can play around with http://www.sassmeister.com/ .  But what's your actual goal here?

Comment: Well, I want all elements of a certain class to be styled in a certain way, but want to change only one css property if the class' element is an anchor. I was curious if SASS supports something like this in a concise way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a solution, it's a little bit tricky, but it works fine.

```
.class {
    color: yellow;

    &:hover {
        color: blue;
    }
    &[href] {
        color: white;

        &:hover {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great example!

Comment: @disinfor Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice hack using the `href` attribute!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to write a mixin

```
  @mixin sample($color,$hovercolor) {
      margin: 1px;
    background: black;
    color: $color;

    &:hover {
        color: $hovercolor;
    }
  }

    .class{ @include sample(white,red)}
    a{ @include sample(yello,yellow)}
```

Hope this helps